# Windows Phone connection to ASP webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to call ASP webservice with my windows phone app, by using this 
[tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application)

I tried many different ways to do it(connecting emulator app to local webservice, connecting emulator app to webservice set on the server) and finally connecting to webservice set on server, by using device. But every time it failed with 404 error.

Can anyone give me some tips or guides how to do this properly? Cause i need connection to webservice, because i need some date from my database and it is the only way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

404 means not found
What is the your url for calling the service?

Comment: I know what does 404 mean. I use smarterasp.net free-trial hosting. To upload my webservice i use Web Deploy. So my final address is http://paremare-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

Comment: But this is a web site, what is the url of the ws endpoint like in the example http://www.contoso.com/api/Books

Comment: i thought it should be /api/books , but it gives me XML error. How can i check or set path to the controller?

Comment: try `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy 
    = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;` in the web api Application_Start